# Laravel seeding results in Null timestamp

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4, laravel-seeding

So i had a seeder for Languages Table (`LanguageTableSeeder`) as follows:

```
DB::table('languages')->insert([
    'name'        => 'English',
    'flag'        => '',
    'abbr'        => 'en',
    'script'    => 'Latn',
    'native'    => 'English',
    'active'    => '1',
    'default'    => '1',
]);

    $this->command->info('Language seeding successful.');
```

But this resulted in `created_at` and `updated_at` fields to be Null in database. i looked up the pre shipped `UsersTabeSeeder` and changed my `LanguageTableSeeder` to mach the exact same format:

```
DB::table('languages')->delete();

$languages = [
    [
        'name' => 'English',
        'flag' => '',
        'abbr' => 'en',
        'script' => 'Latn',
        'native' => 'English',
        'active' => '1',
        'default' => '1',
    ],
];

foreach ($languages as $language){
    Language::create($language);
}
```

This also resulted in `created_at` and `updated_at` fields to be Null which is odd because when i look up at Users Table in my data base they have `created_at` and `updated_at` fields to be set at the exact time of running the seeder.

So here is my question. Why is this happening? and is it necessary to use:

```
'created_at' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
'updated_at' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
```

to get filled timestamp when seeding?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> Auto timestamp saving is only for  Eloquent feature so you need to do manually like  below for non eloquent feature

```
DB::table('languages')->insert([
    'name'        => 'English',
    'flag'        => '',
    'abbr'        => 'en',
    'script'    => 'Latn',
    'native'    => 'English',
    'active'    => '1',
    'default'    => '1',
    'created_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'updated_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')

]);
```

OR do it eloquently(Like you have seen in auto generated seeds like UserTableSeeder)

```
    $language = new Language();
    $language ->name = 'English';
    $language->flag'  = '',
    $language ->abbr  = 'en',
    $language->script ='Latn',
    $language->native ='English',
    $language->active ='1',
    $language->default ='1',
    $language->save();
```

**Why to use carbon?**
Eloquent serves up Carbon for datetime and timestamp columns. By default it will serve up Carbon for the created_at, updated_at, and deleted_at columns. You can customize this in your models extending Eloquent\Model.

`Carbon\Carbon extends \DateTime`, so there is no loss of functionality by using Carbon in favor of DateTime, only more benefit/flexibility.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Why should i use `Carbon` package instead of php's `date` function? and why `UsersTableSeeder` sets timpestamps without using any of the method mentioned above?

Comment: May be your user  table is saved eloquently on seed like $user = new User();
        $user->name = 'Super Admin';
        $user->email = 'system@test.com';
      
        $user->save();

Comment: Thanks for your efforts to enlighten me @sumit :), i can't upvote yet but i accept your answer. Although i understood your point about saving data eloquently but the `UsersTableSeeder` don't do it like this! It's so odd, but i dont have a lot of time to investigate it. maybe later? :)

Comment: don't forget to include `use Carbon\Carbon;`

Answer (score 3):

In users table seeder do this for timestamp. It works for me..

```
    use Carbon\Carbon;



    $faker = Factory::create();
    $date = Carbon::now()->modify('-2 year');
    $createdDate = clone($date);
    DB::table('users')->insert([

        [

            'name' => "XYZ",
            'slug' => "xyz",
            'email' => "xyz@test.com",
            'password' => bcrypt('secret'),
            'bio' => $faker->text(rand(250, 300)),
            'created_at' => $createdDate,
            'updated_at' => $createdDate

        ],
```